# How to group by week in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: linq, group-by, .net-core, entity-framework-core, week-number

In Entity Framework 6 I can use [`SqlFunctions.DatePart()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487171.aspx) method:

```
var byWeek = data.GroupBy(x => SqlFunctions.DatePart("week", x.Date));
```

But these classes (`DbFunctions` and `SqlFunctions` are not available in Entity Framework Core) ([reference](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/6795)).

So my question is **How can I group by week in Entity Framework core?**

Comment: Since currently all EF Core queries having `GroupBy` clause are processed in memory, you could safely use `x.Date.DayOfYear / 7` or something like that.

Comment: @IvanStoev not anymore. group-by querys are compiled to sql since ef core 2.1. see my answer for an working example.

Comment: Note: To anyone finding this make sure you understand the difference between week and iso_week and which you want. The year of an iso week is not always the same as the calendar year (eg. in 2020 Week 1 began on 2010-12-30). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My current workaround for the missing functionality is

```
var firstMondayOfYear = this.GetFirstMondayOfYear(DateTime.Now.Year);
var entries =
    this.entitiesService.FindForLastMonths(this.CurrentUser.Id, 6)
        .GroupBy(x => ((int)(x.Date - firstMondayOfYear).TotalDays / 7))
```

The function `GetFirstMondayOfYear`:

```
private DateTime GetFirstMondayOfYear(int year)
{
    var dt = new DateTime(year, 1, 1);
    while (dt.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Monday)
    {
        dt = dt.AddDays(1);
    }

    return dt;
}
```

This grouping gives the week number for the current year and negative values for previous years.

Later you can get the week name by using this getter:

```
public string WeekName
{
    get
    {
        var year = DateTime.Now.AddYears((int)Math.Floor(this.WeekNumber / 52.0)).Year;
        var weekNumber = this.WeekNumber % 52;
        while (weekNumber < 0)
        {
            weekNumber += 52;
        }

        return $"{year}, W{weekNumber}";
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this entire query is going to be done in memory so will likely be very slow.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to make use of the datepart SQL function by wrapping it with the DbFunctionAttribute.
Tricky part is to tell ef core not to handle the datepart type parameter as a string. Example:

DbContext:

```cs
public int? DatePart(string datePartArg, DateTime? date) => throw new Exception();

public void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
    var methodInfo = typeof(DbContext).GetRuntimeMethod(nameof(DatePart), new[] { typeof(string), typeof(DateTime) });
    modelBuilder
        .HasDbFunction(methodInfo)
        .HasTranslation(args => new SqlFunctionExpression(nameof(DatePart), typeof(int?), new[]
                {
                        new SqlFragmentExpression(args.ToArray()[0].ToString()),
                        args.ToArray()[1]
                }));
}
```

Query:

```cs
repository.GroupBy(x => dbContext.DatePart("week", x.CreatedAt));
```

some more info: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/10404

Answer (score 0):

I happened to be already using a view, so I just added extra columns to that view representing the week, month and year - for easy grouping via EF Core.

```
OrderDateDt,
DATEPART(week, OrderDateDt) OrderDateDt_Week,
DATEPART(month, OrderDateDt) OrderDateDt_Month,
DATEPART(year, OrderDateDt) OrderDateDt_Year,
```

Comment: Note that datepart(week) cannot be used for an indexed view but I think datepart(iso_week) can.

Comment: also since I answered this I learnt more about ISO_WEEK than I cared to - so be sure to look into which suits your needs. Also ISO_WEEK for today (12/30/19) is actually 1 as it is part of the first week of next year - so you can't use `year` or you'll end up with 12/30/19 being week one of 2019 which is not right!