# Group By week - Entity Framework Core

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core

I am new to ET Core and I am looking for a way to group by week (DateTime column) and get the counts from LINQ.

Can someone please help me to do this?

Thanks.

Ex:
[Need to get this same result from LINQ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBRkW.png)

Comment: EF Core doesn't implement Group By yet.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42675153/how-to-group-by-week-in-entity-framework-core

Comment: Any workarounds?

Comment: I checked those posts but those return the Week Number. But i am looking for something like that in the picture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF Core 2.0 doesn't implement GROUP BY.

You can use FromSql to [execute a raw SQL query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql) and map it to an entity, or you can create a VIEW and map it to an entity as if it were a table, eg :

```
class BlogPostCount
{
    public int BlogID{get;set;}
    public int Count {get;set;}         
}


var query = "SELECT BlogID,Count(*) as Count from BlogPosts group by BlogID";
var counts = context.BlogPostCounts.FromSQL(query).ToList();
```